# How to switch databases in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I am changing database name here but it is not effective to change the database

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql2.database', $dbName);
Config::set('database.default', 'mysql2');
```

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the database in laravel like this

```
           Config::set('database.connections.mysql2.database', $dbName);
           Config::set('database.default', 'mysql2');
           DB::reconnect('mysql2');
```

or you can use

```
DB::setDefaultConnection('mysql2');
```